# Python 3.2 script not working and/or importing tkinter when running from Linux desktop

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, ubuntu-12.04, desktop

I'm really puzzled by this, but the answer is probably quite simple and just can't see it:

I have a series of python modules that work fine from within the python interpreter, but nothing happens when running from a GUI situation. I've tried creating a .desktop file, adding shebangs, changing permissions to 777 and renaming to .pyw for all the modules. A single test module works fine on its own, so I know that it's not a typo error.

If I click the main module .pyw file and click 'Run' from the system dialogue nothing happens at all. Similarly the .py file (and the .desktop via menu)... nothing. Here is the start of my code:#

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk, imp, sys


root = tk.Tk()
msg = tk.messagebox
sdg = tk.simpledialog

import capitaliser_cfg as cfg, fileio as io
imp.reload(cfg) ; imp.reload(io) 

### GO AND GET COUNTY LIST ####
# Nb: attach to config for simplicity
cfg.counties = io.getfilelist("counties.txt", "London")

if not type(cfg.counties)==list:
    k = msg.showerror(cfg.version, cfg.counties)
    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()

### GO AND GET DICTIONARY ####
cfg.tempdict = [[],[],[]]
cfg.spelldict = io.getdictionary("addressdict.txt","roda","Road")
if not type(cfg.spelldict)==dict:
    k = msg.showerror(cfg.version, cfg.spelldict)
    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()


import thinbutton as tb, labelradio as lr, fieldblock as fb, bigbutton as bb 
import textblock as tx, padding as pd, widget_tools as wt
import capitaliser_mth as mth
import capitaliser_bnd as bnd


imp.reload(tb) ; imp.reload(lr) ; imp.reload(fb) ; imp.reload(bb)
imp.reload(tx) ; imp.reload(pd) ; imp.reload(wt) ;
imp.reload(mth)
imp.reload(bnd)
```

If I put k = msg.showerror("xxxx","yyyy") after the line sdg = tk.simpledialog, still nothing happens which leads me to believe that tkinter is not loading for some reason.

Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: What happend if you the run code in the terminal: `python script_name.py` ?

Comment: Good question, I get:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "capitaliser.pyw", line 6, in <module>
    msg = tk.messagebox
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox'. Seems to indicate that that I am trying to run 2 versions of tkinter, perhaps ?

Comment: Add full traceback to you question. And mark in code line from traceback (line 6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 2 try:

```
import tkMessageBox
import tkSimpleDialog

msg = tkMessageBox
sdg = tkSimpleDialog
```

or simpler:

```
import tkMessageBox as msg
import tkSimpleDialog as sdk
```

For Python 3 try:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog

msg = messagebox
sdg = simpledialog
```

or simpler:

```
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import simpledialog as sdg
```

Comment: OOO thanks, works like a dream. Question is, what is so different about my coding ? One good thing is I've just learnt about traceback, didn't know it existed, but it didn't help in this case ... it didn't return any errors (nor did sys).

Comment: You can see traceback only if you run code in terminal. And this time traceback helped - "line 6", "object has no attribute" was clue to find solution. Some libs have more files/elements and you have to import each element separately (this way you don't have unwanted elements in memory). By the way: I use simple editor Geany (on Linux Mint) to write code and Geany alwasy run code in terminal so I can see errors and I can use "print" to see values in tested code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I started programming many years ago on Unix and 'C', changed to MSDOS and QB, then Windows and VB. Recently I've made the decision to remove all Windows systems, hence a migration (back) to Linux and Python. So far so good!